# Building a Progress Step UI Component using just FLEX and CSS - Help w Labeling positioning?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a ProgressSteps ui component like the one I saw on LinkedIn:

[image]

I want to use flexbox so eventually I can make this component dynamic.. Here's what I currently have (see included code for how this is coded)

Where I could use help is positioning the label at the bottom and centered. I can't figure out how to do this with flexbox and really want to avoid using absolute, defined positioning...

How can I use flexbox to update my code to render like the LinkedIn example?

Thank you

[image]

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 32px;
}

.ProgressStep {
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.ProgressDot {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  max-width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.ProgressBar {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 2px;
}

.ProgressLabel {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
   <div class="ProgressStep">
      <div class="ProgressDot"></div>
      <div class="ProgressBar"></div>
      <div class="ProgressLabel">LabelHere</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ProgressStep">
      <div class="ProgressDot"></div>
      <div class="ProgressBar"></div>
      <div class="ProgressLabel">LabelHere</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ProgressStep">
      <div class="ProgressDot"></div>
      <div class="ProgressBar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Managed to wrap it to bottom. That hard part is the centering with its relation to the first item. https://jsfiddle.net/sot4uaxk/5/ There could be other flexbox hacks.

Comment: @ManojKumar thanks but the text is not center aligned..

Comment: Exactly why my second line in the comment :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by changing the HTML structure. Move the ProgressLabel elements out of the Container.

This is the result:

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.ProgressStepLabels {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.ProgressStep {
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.ProgressDot {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  max-width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 17px;
}

.ProgressBar {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 2px;
}

.ProgressLabel {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
   <div class="ProgressStep">
      <div class="ProgressDot"></div>
      <div class="ProgressBar"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="ProgressStep">
      <div class="ProgressDot"></div>
      <div class="ProgressBar"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="ProgressStep">
      <div class="ProgressDot"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="ProgressStepLabels">
 <div class="ProgressLabel">LabelHere</div>
 <div class="ProgressLabel">LabelHere</div>
 <div class="ProgressLabel">LabelHere</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work. The Label text is not center aligned under the dots... Were you able to get this to work? If so, would you mind editing w the code snippet running? Thank you

Comment: Thanks but the item is not taking up 100% of the width, out of the outer container... Still a little random... How is the overall width being set. My goal is for the ProgressStep unit to take 100% of the width and then I should be able to set the width of the outer container and the progress steps, dots, labels all render aligned correctly.

Comment: Also, if you change what text is used within the labels, "LabelHere" to things like Profile, Community, Start --- the alignment all breaks...